# Discount Factor Swap curve

Tags: bootstrapping

could you please help with DF from 3Y to 10Y, it's approximately the same but I think there is diff in leap year, how I should correct my excel formula to get the Bloomberg values?

I am using formula as

[image]

Bloomberg data
[image]

My Excel
[image]